# Error using the Shipping Updates method in the API Walmart MarketPlace

Tags: php, curl, walmart-api

I am writing about the error that I get in the API Walmart MarketPlace. Error using Shipping Updates API method https://developer.walmart.com/api/ca/mp/orders#operation/shippingUpdatesCA. Despite my efforts to solve the problem, the error was not resolved. Repeated appeals to the Walmart support service did not give anything - they do not even try to delve into the essence and respond template, simply not wanting to help me.
Attached the data of the API request and the answer that show the error that I received. As you can see from the answer, I received the following error message:
System_error.gmp_order_api. The System Is Faced with Some Inner Error
I would be grateful if you could help me find a way to solve this problem.
Thanks for your time and help.

I tried to make tracks for updating, requests and answers of API below.

Request

```
curl --location 'https://marketplace.walmartapis.com/v3/ca/orders/ORDER_ID/shipping' \
--header 'WM_SVC.NAME: Walmart Marketplace' \
--header 'WM_TENANT_ID: WALMART.CA' \
--header 'WM_LOCALE_ID: en_CA' \
--header 'WM_QOS.CORRELATION_ID: ...' \
--header 'WM_SEC.TIMESTAMP: ...' \
--header 'WM_SEC.AUTH_SIGNATURE: ...' \
--header 'WM_CONSUMER.ID: ...' \
--header 'WM_CONSUMER.CHANNEL.TYPE: ...' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/xml' \
--header 'Accept: application/xml' \
--header 'Host: marketplace.walmartapis.com' \
--data '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<orderShipment
  xmlns:ns2="http://walmart.com/mp/v3/orders"
  xmlns:ns3="http://walmart.com/">
    <orderLines>
        <orderLine>
            <lineNumber>1</lineNumber>
            <shipFromCountry>US</shipFromCountry>
            <orderLineStatuses>
                <orderLineStatus>
                    <status>Shipped</status>
                    <statusQuantity>
                        <unitOfMeasurement>EACH</unitOfMeasurement>
                        <amount>1</amount>
                    </statusQuantity>
                    <trackingInfo>
                        <shipDateTime>2023-03-20:10:00.000Z</shipDateTime>
                        <carrierName>
                            <carrier>UPS</carrier>
                        </carrierName>
                        <methodCode>Standard</methodCode>
                        <trackingNumber>TRACKING_NUMBER</trackingNumber>
                    </trackingInfo>
                </orderLineStatus>
            </orderLineStatuses>
        </orderLine>
    </orderLines>
</orderShipment>'
```

Response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:errors xmlns:ns2="http://walmart.com/">
    <ns2:error>
        <ns2:code>SYSTEM_ERROR.GMP_ORDER_API</ns2:code>
        <ns2:info>System encountered some internal error.</ns2:info>
        <ns2:severity>ERROR</ns2:severity>
        <ns2:category>DATA</ns2:category>
        <ns2:causes/>
        <ns2:errorIdentifiers/>
    </ns2:error>
</ns2:errors>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
source: <orderShipment xmlns:ns2="http://walmart.com/mp/v3/orders" xmlns:ns3="http://walmart.com/">
replace: <orderShipment xmlns="http://walmart.com/mp/v3/orders" xmlns:ns3="http://walmart.com/">
```

I encountered the same problem as you did, and it was resolved by simply replacing it. The example in Walmart's documentation is incorrect.